# Dag dependency view is not showing the list of dags in Airflow 2.1.3

Tags: airflow, apache-arrow, airflow-webserver

We have successfully installed Airflow 2.1.3 , when we click on Dag dependency view from the browse drop down , it shows none..

Do we need to enable in any place ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in Airflow 2.1.3
It was fixed in Airflow 2.2.0 (See [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17990))

Currently Airflow 2.2.0 is in beta testing it's expected to be released in the beginning of October.

Comment: Hi Elad. We have just updated Airflow to Airflow 2.2.2 but still we cant see the Dag dependencies page. Its still remains blank. Could you pls help if any update